# Data migration with insert/update conditions and multiple databases

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-update

So I have two DB's, one used for draft one used for live stuff.

```
// Connect to the draft database
$connDraft = mysqli_connect('###.###.##.##','user','pass') OR die("There was a problem connecting to the draft database.");
// Select database
mysqli_select_db($connDraft, "draftDB") OR die("There was a problem selecting the draft database.");

// Connect to the live database
$connLive = mysqli_connect('###.###.##.##','user','pass') OR die("There was a problem connecting to the live database.");
// Select database
mysqli_select_db($connLive, "liveDB") OR die("There was a problem selecting the live database.");
```

The table structure will be the same, as will the table names and everything. I simply need to:

if entry_id exists in live, update otherwise insert a new record.

**A** - Copying from table to table i'd use

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

**B** - Insert vs update i'd use

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

**C** - And moving from 1 DB to another, i'd use **???**

```
INSERT INTO liveDB.TableA
SELECT * FROM draftDB.TableB
```

My confusion is how to use **A** & **B** in tandem. I'm having difficulty finding a sample online. Also, is **C** is a proper way to accomplish this.

A sample table structure would be...

entry_id, title, status, date_created, data_edited